# Android Service for PubNub

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver, android-service, pubnub

I have implemented PubNub subscribe and publish code. My code is working fine on activity. But now I want to execute that code in background with the help of service class. I have created my class extending the `IntentService`. And I am subscribing to pubnub channel in `onCreate` method. But whenever I am running the app service is immediately stopping without showing pubnub status. I am getting following pubnub error. I have linked pubnub required libraries too.

```
04-09 23:39:32.621: D/Service Message(10033): error[Error: 100-1] : Timeout Occurred
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    public void startService(View v){
        startService(new Intent(this, MyService.class));
    }

    public void stopService(View v){
        stopService(new Intent(this, MyService.class));
    }


}
```

**PubnubHandler.java**

```
public class PubnubHandler{

    public static final String GLOBAL_CHANNEL = "my_channel_name";
    public static final String PUBLISH_KEY = 
            "my_publish_key";
    public static final String SUBSCRIBE_KEY = 
            "my_subscribe_key";
    private Context context;
    private Pubnub pubnub;


    public PubnubHandler(Context context) {

        this.context = context;
        pubnub = new Pubnub(PUBLISH_KEY, SUBSCRIBE_KEY);
        pubnub.setRetryInterval(1000);
    }

    public void notifyUser(String message) {

        final String msg = message;
        Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());

        handler.post(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {

                Toast.makeText(context, msg, 0).show();

            }
        });



    }

    public void subscribe() {

        Callback callback = new Callback() {
            @Override
            public void connectCallback(String channel, Object message) {
                Log.d("Service Message", "Subscribed");
            }

            @Override
            public void disconnectCallback(String channel, Object message) {
                Log.d("Service Message", "Disconnected");
            }

            public void reconnectCallback(String channel, Object message) {
                Log.d("Service Message", "Reconnected");
            }

            @Override
            public void successCallback(String channel, final Object message) {
                Log.d("Service Message", "Message : "+message.toString());
            }

            @Override
            public void errorCallback(String channel, PubnubError error) {
                Log.d("Service Message", "error"+error.toString());
            }
        };

        try {
            pubnub.subscribe(GLOBAL_CHANNEL, callback);
        } catch (PubnubException e) {
            System.out.println(e.toString());
        }
    }

    public void unsubscribe() {
        pubnub.unsubscribe(GLOBAL_CHANNEL);
    }

    public void publish(String message) {

        Callback callback = new Callback() {
            public void successCallback(String channel, Object response) {

            }
            public void errorCallback(String channel, PubnubError error) {

                notifyUser("Something went wrong. Try again.");
            }
        };
        pubnub.publish(GLOBAL_CHANNEL, message , callback);


    }

}
```

**MyService.java**

```
public class MyService extends IntentService {

    public MyService() {
        super("My Service");
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        Toast.makeText(this, "Service Created", 1).show();
        new PubnubHandler(this).subscribe();
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        Toast.makeText(this, "Service Destroyed", 1).show();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent arg0) {

    }
}
```

**manifest**

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.servicedemo"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="16"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <service android:name=".MyService" >
        </service>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Hi Gaurav.  Thank you for asking about Background on Android with PubNub.  This has been solved many times by PubNub staff. You can send a quick email to support@punbub.com for details :-)

Comment: can you post the answer please?

Comment: @PubNub: so why not *post that answer here* and help future visitors avoid having to ask *again*. If you already did so to another question, then please flag this post as a duplicate.

Comment: This might directly answer you question, but might be helpful overall with Android services as it relates to PubNub. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35051528/is-leaving-a-pubnub-subscription-open-in-a-service-optimal

Comment: Just curious if you did contact PubNub support though. If you haven't you should provide log file that capture the repro of this issue. You can [generate logs by using the PubNub debug jar](https://www.pubnub.com/docs/java-se-java/pubnub-java-sdk-troubleshooting-guide). If we solve it there, we'll post answer back here.

Answer (score 4):

You should always do the work in `IntentService`'s `onHandleIntent()`, not in `onCreate()`. The reason because your `IntentService` stops immediately is you haven't supplied any code to `onHandleIntent()`. `IntentService` always shuts down itself when `onHandleIntent()` finishes and there weren't any other `startService()` calls.

In your case, though, calls to `PubNub` API are asynchronous and therefore happen already in background. Maybe you don't need `IntentService` here at all. If you want to create a model object to keep data that will survive `Activity`'s configuration changes, consider using [headless Fragment](http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2013/04/retaining-objects-across-config-changes.html) or plain `Service`.

Answer (score 2):

Try to extend `MyService` from simple `Service` instead of `IntentService`. `IntentService` calls `stopSelf()` just after the last task was completed. This means that there would be no `Context` associated with `PubnubHandler` and the system can just kill a `Thread` where subscribe stuff is running.

Comment: @Dmide Sure, as I understood subscribe is asynchronous call : https://www.pubnub.com/docs/android-java/pubnub-java-sdk